# On MSB and LSB of Diffie Hellman

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

Given generator $g$ of multiplicative cyclic group modulo $p$ a prime and two elements $h_1$ and $h_2$ such that there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively satisfying $g^{x_i}=h_i\bmod p$ at every $i\in\{1,2\}$, the Discrete Logarithm problem is to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ while the Diffie Hellman problem is to find $g^{x_1x_2}\bmod p$. Both these problems do not have polynomial in $\log p$ time algorithm.

Is it possible to find LSB (Least Significant Bit) and MSB (Most Significant Bit) of $g^{x_1x_2}\bmod p$ in polynomial in $\log p$ time?

Comment: What is LSB and MSB?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich a quick google search reveals the definition of the acronyms: most significant and least significant bits, respectively.

Comment: I think a good rule about posts is that I shouldn't have to google acronyms. If I understand it correctly one question is if the representative of $g^{x_1x_2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ between $0$ and $p-1$ is even or odd. (Probably the one between $-p/2$ and $p/2$ would be just as interesting) The other question is not clear to me, the first binary digit of any integer is $1$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich as you say .. it has at most $1+\log p $ bits of information and we seek if the least or the highest bit are one or zero. The interest in MSBs comes from section 6.2 in https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1506.pdf.